# Issue with references when creating exe using py2exe for my python script

Tags: python, py2exe, python-2.6

I am using py2exe to create win64 exe from my python script ie. test.py. I followed py2exe tutorial and created a setup.py and I executed python setup.py install and then python setup.py py2exe. It does create an exe. However my problem is when I run the exe it complains about not finding references. because my test.py has imports files from other folders  For example: the root directores are 'core' and 'test'. 'test' directory has test.py, 'core' as core_script.py and another child directory 'math', 'core/math' has math_script.py. so test.py uses imports from '../core/core_script.py' and "../core/math/math_script.py'.
import code in test.py looks like this:
from core import core_script

my setup.py looks like this:
 from distutils.core import setup
   2 import py2exe
   3 
   4 setup(console=['test.py'])

question is: how can I modify setup.up to resolve the reference issues. Do I path.append in setup.py?